# saml - when is HOK certificate used vs IDP and SP certs

Tags: certificate, saml, saml-2.0

I am trying to understand the SAML 2 protocol and in that process got a little bit lost with the signature and certificate business.

Basically, I am not clear of when each of the certs are used.

1. Service Provider Meta Data and Identity Provider Metadata - do we need to generate certificates/keys as a part of the SP and IDP metadata? If so how/when will these certs be used?
2. HOK token also needs a certificate - when does that come into picture? Does the principal's certificate/public key needs to be exported to the IDP also along withe SP's certificate?
3. When using bearer tokens (they do not have any certs associated with the principal) is the SAML response/assertion still signed? Is it different from the ds:keyInfo in the SAML response in this case?

Thanks a bunch for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

1.
Certificates in SP and IDP metadata are typically used for two purposes digital signing and digital encryption. Attribute "usage" on metadata makes the discrimination. Certificates are typically included in the metadata, but they could also be ommited and provided out-of-band (e.g. by direct configuration in IDP and SP, if supported). These keys identify the SP and IDP machines, they have nothing to do with the users.

When SP sends a SAML message towards IDP the message can be digitally signed using SP's private key (whose public key + certificate is included in the SP metadata and available to IDP), IDP is able to verify the SP's signature using the SP's public key.

When SP wants to encrypt part of the SAML data (whole message, assertion, name ID, attribute, ...) it uses public key declared in the IDP's metadata, IDP then decrypts the data using its private key.

Sometimes metadata can contain multiple signing or encryption keys, e.g. in case of certificate rollover before expiration.

2.
Bearer mechanisms are used to make sure that the entity (e.g. web browser) who is presenting a SAML message is allowed to do so. In SAML WebSSO AuthnResponse message gets issued by the IDP, but is delivered to the SP by the browser. HoK SubjectConfiguration tells that we are identifying the presenter by making sure that it can prove posession of a private key whose public key/certificate is included in the SubjectConfirmation element. This is typically done by usage of SSL/TLS Client Authentication (i.e. user installs private key in browser and uses it to authenticate toward SAML service when opening the HTTPS scheme with SSL/TLS).

So here we are dealing with keys issued directly to users, not to SP/IDP services. Whether or not you need to import user's certificate(s) to the IDP or not is IDP-implementation specific.

3.
Yes, the messages will still be signed (when configured to be) and KeyInfo in the SAML response will be the same in both cases.

Cheers,
Vladimir Schafer